# How to transform sitemap XML file into breadcrumb using XSLT in SDL Tridion?

Tags: asp.net, xslt, tridion, tridion-2011

I have a XML file for sitemap, here it is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<siteMap>
  <siteMapNode url="/" title="Home" tcmId="tcm:142-2-4">
    <siteMapNode url="/controls" title="Controls" tcmId="tcm:142-1131-4" type="structure group" />
    <siteMapNode url="/css" title="CSS" tcmId="tcm:142-1134-4" type="structure group" />
    <siteMapNode url="/js" title="JS" tcmId="tcm:142-1133-4" type="structure group" />
    <siteMapNode url="/xslt" title="XSLT" tcmId="tcm:142-1132-4" type="structure group"   />
    <siteMapNode url="/mobile" title="Mobile" tcmId="tcm:142-1165-4" type="structure group" />
    <siteMapNode url="/mobilebiscuitml" title="Mobile BiscuitML" tcmId="tcm:142-1180-4" type="structure group" />
    <siteMapNode url="/system" title="system" tcmId="tcm:142-136-4" type="structure group">
    <siteMapNode url="/system/captcha" title="Captcha" tcmId="tcm:142-260-4" type="structure group" />
    <siteMapNode url="/system/communicator" title="Communicator" tcmId="tcm:142-201-4" type="structure group" />
    <siteMapNode url="/system/errorpages" title="Error Pages" tcmId="tcm:142-322-4" type="structure group" />
    <siteMapNode url="/system/includes" title="includes" tcmId="tcm:142-138-4" type="structure group" />
    <siteMapNode url="/system/masterpages" title="Master Pages" tcmId="tcm:142-139-4" type="structure group" />
    <siteMapNode url="/system/outboundemail" title="Outbound Email" tcmId="tcm:142-199-4" type="structure group" />
    <siteMapNode url="/system/SiteEdit" title="SiteEdit" tcmId="tcm:142-214-4" type="structure group" />
    <siteMapNode url="/system/ui_widgets" title="UI Widgets" tcmId="tcm:142-320-4" type="structure group" />
    <siteMapNode url="/system/webtemplates" title="Web Templates" tcmId="tcm:142-333-4" type="structure group" />
    <siteMapNode url="/system/xml" title="Xml" tcmId="tcm:142-141-4" type="structure group" />
  </siteMapNode>
  <siteMapNode url="/App_GlobalResources" title="Website Labels" tcmId="tcm:142-295-4" type="structure group" />
    <siteMapNode url="/Bpo.aspx" title=" BPO" tcmId="tcm:142-10830-64" type="page" />
    <siteMapNode url="/Careers.aspx" title=" Careers" tcmId="tcm:142-10692-64" type="page" />
    <siteMapNode url="/bpoHitech.aspx" title=" Hitech" tcmId="tcm:142-10710-64" type="page" />
    <siteMapNode url="/news.aspx" title=" News" tcmId="tcm:142-10868-64" type="page" />
    <siteMapNode url="/ISD.html" title="ISD" tcmId="tcm:142-11027-64" type="page" />
    <siteMapNode url="/Services.aspx" title="Services" tcmId="tcm:142-10681-64" type="page" />
    <siteMapNode url="/Knowledge.aspx" title="Knowledge" tcmId="tcm:142-11170-64" type="page" />
  </siteMapNode>
</siteMap>
```

What i've did till now:
create a function in script tag in PT DWT TBB. where,
pageload()
{ id="@@Page.ID@@" }
this TBB inherits a (.cs file) where i defined a id property in a class. create a object of this class type and access the property. used this property as XSLT argument and apply the transformation through xsl.

Any other suggestion'd be good.

Comment: Do you want to do this at publish time or on page request?

Comment: Is the existing implementation you have for Breadcrumbs not usable here?

Comment: Additionally: I believe there is a constraint to use .NET 2.0 only.

Comment: You say you want to use XSLT in an ASP.NET user control, which is (as far as I know) not a language natively supported by ASP.NET user controls. So you'll have to use some native language (e.g. C#) to call whatever XSLT it is you intend to apply.

Comment: @ChrisSummers i want to do this at the time of page request.

Comment: @ArjenStobbe i don't have any other implementation for breadcrumb.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Manoj, The below XSL might help.. I have not tested this, but used it in some past projects the xml structure is slightly different but the below snippet should help you on moving forward in the right direction.

```
 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
     <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="//siteMapNode[@title = '<<Controls>>']">  ---> Node title of the current page
            <div id="breadcrumb">
                <xsl:for-each select="ancestor::siteMapNode"> --> selects the parent and loop through.. 
                    <a href="@url"><xsl:value-of select="@title"/></a> &gt; --> breadcrumb separator ">"
                </xsl:for-each>
                <xsl:value-of select="@title"/>
            </div>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: The web.sitemap file is usually restricted from public access by IIS (just like DLLs and other system files).  So you will most likely need to use C# serverside to apply the Xslt to get the rendered output.

Comment: <xsl:if test="@type='page'"> use to check if node type is page. what should i write to check if node type is current page requested?

Comment: the above code is working fine but it is generating breadcrumbs for all the nodes in sitemap file. so i wrote <xsl:for-each select="//siteMapNode[@tcmId = 'Page.ID']"> to get the current page id. but is not working plz help.

Comment: Question: how are you passing the current page id to the xslt? You are running the code on CDA side, so Page.ID does not work. You have pass the current page via xsltarguments either URL or title or id.

Comment: @RamG can u please tell me how can i pass URL or title or id to my XSL by using user control. i've created a user control which will contain the output of XSL. and render this user control in my tridion page. all i need to know how can i get current page property and pass it to my XSL.

Comment: @RamG i've created a created a user control so that those pages which contain this user control will have the breadcrumb for their page.

Comment: XsltArgumentList xslArgs = new XsltArgumentList();
xslArgs.AddParam("curPage", "", curPageId);.. In your xsl, you need to have the Param declared.. <xsl:param name="curPage"></xsl:param>.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered this?: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x20z8c51.aspx